Find non-overlapping intervals within DNA coordinates
I am trying to find the non-overlapping intervals for the start/end DNA coordinates (on the same chromosome). I am having a hard time developing a function that takes into account two rows on the same exon. The non-overlapping interval must be unique (not overlap with any other intervals).
For ex, on the first row below, the non-overlapping interval would be 1-49, 61-100. But, if you look at the second row, the non-overlapping interval would be 1-69, 81-100. I want non-overlapping, non-overlapping intervals, so the true interval output I want is 1-49, 61-69, 81-100. Ideally, I would like these intervals to bee separated into their own columns (non-overlap_start, non-overlap_end).
*Please note: I have unique intervals per chromosome.
starting DF
chrom        exon_start    exon_end   start1      end1   
1                  1       100        50           60      
1                  1       100        70           80      
1                  150     155        155          160
2                  5       50         25           100     


final DF
chrom   exon_start    exon_end   start1   end1   non_overlap 
1           1             100    50      60      [1-49, 61-69, 81-100]        
1           1             100    70      80      [1-49, 61-69, 81-100] 
1          150             155  155      160      [150-154]
2           5             50     25      100     [5-24] 



Is this something you want?
def find_non_overlap(part):
    minval = part.ex_start.min()
    maxval = part.ex_end.max()
    t = np.array([np.concatenate((
            # add additional True from each side
            np.ones(1 + row.ex_start - minval),
            np.zeros(row.overlap_start - row.ex_start), 
            np.ones(row.overlap_end - row.overlap_start + 1), 
            np.zeros(row.ex_end - row.overlap_end),
            np.ones(1 + maxval - row.ex_end), 
        )) for _, row in part.iterrows()])
    changes = minval + np.flatnonzero(np.diff(np.logical_or.reduce(t)))
    return list(zip(changes[::2], changes[1::2] - 1))
    # return pd.Series(
    #     {'non_overlap_starts': changes[::2], 
    #     'non_overlap_ends': changes[1::2] - 1}
    # )

def calc_intervals(df):
    df = df.copy()
    df['overlap_start'] = df[['ex_start', 'start']].max(axis=1) 
    df['overlap_start'] = df[['overlap_start']].assign(
        t=df.ex_end + 1).min(axis=1)
    df['overlap_end'] = df[['ex_end', 'end']].min(axis=1) 
    df['overlap_end'] = df[['overlap_end']].assign(
        t=df.ex_start - 1).max(axis=1)
    return df.groupby(
        ['chrom', 'ex_start', 'ex_end']
    )[df.columns].apply(
        find_non_overlap, include_groups=False)

df = pd.DataFrame([
    [0, 0, 100, 50, 60],
    [0, 0, 100, 20, 30],
    [0, 0, 100, 25, 40],
    [0, 0, 100, 90, 100],
    [0, 0, 100, 0, 5],
    [1, 10, 50, 5, 15],
    [2, 10, 50, 1, 5],
    [3, 10, 50, 30, 70],
    [4, 10, 50, 5, 55],
    [5, 10, 50, 20, 30],
    [6, 1, 100, 50, 60],
    [6, 1, 100, 70, 80],
    [6, 150, 155, 155, 160],
    [7, 5, 50, 25, 100],
    [8, 0, 5, 0, 1],
    [8, 0, 5, 3, 5],
    [9, 0, 5, 0, 4]
], 
columns=['chrom', 'ex_start', 'ex_end', 'start', 'end'])

calc_intervals(df)

Result is:
chrom  ex_start  ex_end
0      0         100        [(6, 19), (41, 49), (61, 89)]
1      10        50                            [(16, 50)]
2      10        50                            [(10, 50)]
3      10        50                            [(10, 29)]
4      10        50                                    []
5      10        50                  [(10, 19), (31, 50)]
6      1         100       [(1, 49), (61, 69), (81, 100)]
       150       155                         [(150, 154)]
7      5         50                             [(5, 24)]
8      0         5                               [(2, 2)]
9      0         5                               [(5, 5)]

You can join it with your original dataframe if you need this values repeated in every row
UPD: I have changed the algorithm and excluded assumptions that one chromosome has one ex_start-ex_end diapason and that the (start: end) interval is entirely included in the (ex_start: ex_end) interval. Also, I add more test examples. Check if I use the correct logic of overlapping calculations. Your initial examples are 6 and 7 chrom.
Also if size of exons are very big, you can code values monotonically to make this algorithm much faster:
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [0, 3, 1000000000, 50, 60],
    [0, 3, 1000000000, 10, 12],
    [1, 3, 10, 5, 30],
], columns=['chrom', 'ex_start', 'ex_end', 'start', 'end'])


values = pd.concat([df.ex_start, df.ex_end, df.start, df.end])
values = pd.concat(
    [values, values + 1, values - 1]
).sort_values().unique()
code = dict(zip(values, np.arange(0, len(values))))
decode = dict(zip(np.arange(0, len(values)), values))

df_ = df.copy()
df_ = df_.replace(code)

pd.Series([
    [(decode[i],decode[j]) for (i, j) in t] 
    for t in calc_intervals(df_)])
# It's much easier to decode inside find_non_overlap function

Results:
0    [(3, 9), (13, 49), (61, 1000000000)]
1                                [(3, 4)]


I've edited my examples for clarity.

In this case, it would not be easy to join because many regions share the same chromosome number. It would be better if you can edit your code to include those original columns. Also, I am getting a ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed

Do you mean there is a possible situation when different sets of exon_start exon_end pairs exist inside one chrome? If so, could you please add this to your example because I am unsure about how it should be calculated.

Just edited my example @Bogdan Shevchenko

can exons be overlapped?

If they can't, look on updated version

This can be done some like this (if I understood the problem):

group_by the chromosomes, exon start and end
generate range for exons' lengths
merge overlapping intervals
remove them, and we'll have the non-overlapping intervals

For example, here is the code with your example data:
import pandas as pd

def find_non_overlapping_intervals(df):
    df['non_overlap'] = ''

    # Grouping by chromosome and exon to handle each exon separately
    grouped = df.groupby(['chrom', 'exon_start', 'exon_end'])

    def process_group(group):
        # full exon range
        exon_start, exon_end = group['exon_start'].iloc[0], group['exon_end'].iloc[0]

        # Mark the intervals of 'start1' and 'end1'
        covered_intervals = []
        for _, row in group.iterrows():
            covered_intervals.append((row['start1'], row['end1']))

        # Sort and merge overlapping intervals
        covered_intervals.sort()
        merged_intervals = []
        current_start, current_end = covered_intervals[0]
        
        for start, end in covered_intervals[1:]:
            if start <= current_end:  # Overlapping or touching intervals
                current_end = max(current_end, end)
            else:
                merged_intervals.append((current_start, current_end))
                current_start, current_end = start, end
        merged_intervals.append((current_start, current_end))  # Add the last interval

        # Finding the non-overlapping intervals
        non_overlapping_intervals = []
        prev_end = exon_start - 1
        for start, end in merged_intervals:
            if start > prev_end + 1:
                non_overlapping_intervals.append((prev_end + 1, start - 1))
            prev_end = end
        if prev_end < exon_end:
            non_overlapping_intervals.append((prev_end + 1, exon_end))

        # additional formating
        non_overlap_str = ', '.join([f"{start}-{end}" for start, end in non_overlapping_intervals])
        group['non_overlap'] = f"[{non_overlap_str}]"

        return group

    df = grouped.apply(process_group)

    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    
    return df

# Example input dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'chrom': [1, 1, 2],
    'exon_start': [1, 1, 5],
    'exon_end': [100, 100, 50],
    'start1': [50, 70, 25],
    'end1': [60, 80, 100]
})

df = find_non_overlapping_intervals(df)

After printing I got the expected output as per the example data
print(df)

   chrom  exon_start  exon_end  start1  end1            non_overlap
0      1           1       100      50    60  [1-49, 61-69, 81-100]
1      1           1       100      70    80  [1-49, 61-69, 81-100]
2      2           5        50      25   100                 [5-24]


The non-overlap column is correct for the first two rows, but the 3rd row should have a non-overlap 5-24, because the exon_start/end is different. The 81-100 should have the coordinates from the second row.

Actually, you are right, I missed the chromosome factor. For this, I think we can:
. group_by the chromosomes, exon start and end
. generate range for exons' lengths
. merge overlapping intervals
. remove them, and we'll have the non-overlapping intervals
Let me edit my answer also.
